# How to select only the partitions that should be truncated in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, truncate, partition

Given 2 variables with values:
    `v_days1 = 30
 v_days2 = 367`

And below partitions from `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS`:

```
TABLE_NAME  PARTITION_NAME        HIGH_VALUE (LONG datatype)
TABLENAME   partitionname1_P30    30
TABLENAME   partitionname2_P60    60 
TABLENAME   partitionname3_P90    90
TABLENAME   partitionname4_P120   120
TABLENAME   partitionname5_P150   150
TABLENAME   partitionname6_P180   180 
TABLENAME   partitionname7_210    210
TABLENAME   partitionname8_P240   240
TABLENAME   partitionname9_P270   270
TABLENAME   partitionname10_P300  300
TABLENAME   partitionname11_P330  330
TABLENAME   partitionname12_P360  367
```

How to select `HIGH_VALUE` that are not equal to `v_days1` and `v_days2` in `all_tab_partitions` and truncate the corresponding partitions?

For this sample, truncate partitions `partitionname2_P60` to `partitionname11_P330`.

```
FOR rec IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE       
        FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLENAME'
        AND HIGH_VALUE NOT IN (v_days1, v_days2) LOOP

        <TRUNCATE PARTITIONS WITH HIGH_VALUE 60 TO 333 
        /TRUNCATE PARTITIONS WITH HIGH_VALUE NOT EQUAL TO 30 AND 367>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `high_value` datatype is of `Long` you cannot directly use it in `where` clause. You need to first covert into `lob` then you can use. However in this case it become difficult to use it since you have to look in between a range of number. So you can modify the solution little bit and achieve your requirement as below;

```
DECLARE
  v_days1 varchar2(10) := '20';
  v_days2 varchar2(10) := '367';
  l_var    VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_sql   VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (SELECT table_name,
    partition_name,
    high_value
  FROM all_tab_partitions
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLENAME'
 --WHERE high_value NOT IN  ( v_days1)
  )
  LOOP
    l_var:=rec.high_value;
    --dbms_output.put_line('partition Name'||rec.partition_name);

    --IF l_var between '20' and '367' THEN   
      IF (l_var NOT IN (v_days1 ,v_days2)) THEN  
      dbms_output.put_line('partition Name'||rec.partition_name);
      v_sql:= 'ALTER TABLE '||rec.table_name||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||rec.partition_name ;

      EXECUTE immediate v_sql ;
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: `HIGH_VALUE` from `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS` has `LONG datatype`. I tried your suggestion and got error: `PL/SQL: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype` and `PLS-00364: loop index variable 'REC' use is invalid`

Comment: @dcdum2018 Please read my comments and see the revised answer,

Comment: `IF statement` is not truncating the partitions. `v_days1` and `v_days2` are `HIGH_VALUES` whose `partitions` should not be truncated while the rest should be truncated. For this sample, `partitions` with `HIGH_VALUE=30 and 367` should be NOT be truncated while `HIGH_VALUE=60 to 330` should be truncated.

Comment: @dcdum2018 I thought you would modify the code as per your need. Please see the updated answer. I just gave an example and showed how you could achieve your requirement.